# Ruby on rails WebSocket connection to 'wss://ws15.hotjar.com/api/v2/client/ws' failed: WebSocket is closed due to suspension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, hotjar

I want to connect my website with hotjar but I have a 400 error. Actually, I just put the JS tag in the header. If you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. My website have to use a https://